# jQuery to get HTML value and find and replace $ or £ in content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im a little new to JS / jQuery and this site is on shopify so i cant do much with functionality so trying to work around with JS but i need to grab the values, strip the currency then add them together and re-display but this is as far as ive got but not working...

Any ideas?

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var a = $(".cart-total span").html().replaceText(/$|£/gi, "");
  var b = $("#estimated-shipping em").html().replaceText(/$|£/gi, "");
  var total = a + b;
  $('.cart-finalTotal span').html("£" + total);
  console.log(total);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-right">


  <p class="cart-total">Sub-Total<span class="money">£249.00</span>
  </p>
  <p class="cart-vat">VAT 20% (included)<span class="money">£49.80</span>
  </p>
  <p class="cart-delivery">Delivery<span class="money" id="estimated-shipping">+ <em>$9.00</em></span>
  </p>
  <p class="cart-finalTotal">Total<span class="money">£249.00</span>
  </p>
  <div class="cart-checkout">


    <button class="button button-primary button-add-to-cart button-pay-now" type="submit" name="checkout"><span class="icom-lock"></span>Pay Now</button>

    <br>
    <br>


    <div class="additional-checkout-buttons">
      <p>Or checkout with</p>
      <img id="applePayButton" style="display: none" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" onload="typeof createApplyPayButton === 'function' ? createApplyPayButton(this) : window.addEventListener('applePayReady', (function(){createApplyPayButton(this)}).bind(this))">
      <input type="image" name="goto_pp" value="paypal_express" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please specify "not working"...

Comment: I think your regular expression is wrong. $ sign means end of string. You should escape it with \

Comment: I added \ before $ but in console i see: $(...).html(...).replaceText is not a function

Comment: @Connum If you read the description i said " not working"

Comment: I am perfectly able to read descriptions, that's why I asked you to elaborate on "not working". Because "doesn't work" is simply one of the worst descriptions you can give if you want to get help. But if don't want to get help, that's fine by me...

Comment: Of course i wanted some help, hence why i said i needed it and that it was not working lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape your regular expression $ with a backslash.

Replace text is not a jquery function just use `text().replace(/\$|£/gi, '')`

Also convert those strings into numbers by using `parseFloat(a, 10)`

Comment: I tried: var a = $(".cart-total span").html().replaceText(/\$|£/gi, "");
    var b = $("#estimated-shipping em").html().replaceText(/\$|£/gi, ""); is that correct? sorry i am new to JS

Comment: That worked great, i added to total .toFixed(2) which made decimal but worked cool thanks

Comment: How would i find and replace the $ on the estimated_shipping?

Comment: I tried: $("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$/,'£'); but id not change it

Comment: that replaces the $ in the text variable but you then need to actually update the DOM  something like: $("#estimated-shipping em").text(my_new_variable)

Comment: Weird, i done this: https://jsfiddle.net/7cwk4a1n/4/ and when i added to the code on the shopify template its not replacing the $ with £ and its also not doing the grand total... not sure why...

Comment: Changed to 1500 and seem to have done the trick ;) thanks for your help mate!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example, however you are adding dollar and pound here which seems to be wrong.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var a = parseFloat($(".cart-total span").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, ""));

  var b = parseFloat($("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, ""));
  var total = a + b;
  $('.cart-finalTotal span').html("£" + total.toFixed(2));

}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-right">


  <p class="cart-total">Sub-Total<span class="money">£249.00</span>
  </p>
  <p class="cart-vat">VAT 20% (included)<span class="money">£49.80</span>
  </p>
  <p class="cart-delivery">Delivery<span class="money" id="estimated-shipping">+ <em>$9.00</em></span>
  </p>
  <p class="cart-finalTotal">Total<span class="money">£249.00</span>
  </p>
  <div class="cart-checkout">


    <button class="button button-primary button-add-to-cart button-pay-now" type="submit" name="checkout"><span class="icom-lock"></span>Pay Now</button>

    <br>
    <br>


    <div class="additional-checkout-buttons">
      <p>Or checkout with</p>
      <img id="applePayButton" style="display: none" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" onload="typeof createApplyPayButton === 'function' ? createApplyPayButton(this) : window.addEventListener('applePayReady', (function(){createApplyPayButton(this)}).bind(this))">
      <input type="image" name="goto_pp" value="paypal_express" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yea i know, its pulling out the shipping in shopify cart as $ for some reason and dont know why so going to replace with JS as a temp fixture for now.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

- instead to escape you can use the format [$£] in regex
- round numbers after adding them
- use replace instead of replaceText
- use text instead of html to set the result into the span

```js
$(function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var a = $(".cart-total span").html().replace(/[$£]/gi, "");
    var b = $("#estimated-shipping em").html().replace(/[$£]/gi, "");
    var total = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
    total = parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    $('.cart-finalTotal span').text("£" + total);
    console.log(total);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>


<div class="cart-right">


    <p class="cart-total">Sub-Total<span class="money">£249.00</span>
    </p>
    <p class="cart-vat">VAT 20% (included)<span class="money">£49.80</span>
    </p>
    <p class="cart-delivery">Delivery<span class="money" id="estimated-shipping">+ <em>$9.00</em></span>
    </p>
    <p class="cart-finalTotal">Total<span class="money">£249.00</span>
    </p>
    <div class="cart-checkout">


        <button class="button button-primary button-add-to-cart button-pay-now" type="submit" name="checkout"><span class="icom-lock"></span>Pay Now</button>

        <br>
        <br>


        <div class="additional-checkout-buttons">
            <p>Or checkout with</p>
            <img id="applePayButton" style="display: none" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" onload="typeof createApplyPayButton === 'function' ? createApplyPayButton(this) : window.addEventListener('applePayReady', (function(){createApplyPayButton(this)}).bind(this))">
            <input type="image" name="goto_pp" value="paypal_express" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```